# Invoking member function on invalid object

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

In visual studio you can invoke function on already deleted object:

```
class Foo {
    void bar() {
        ...
    }
};
```

you can actually execute following code without errors:

```
Foo * foo = new Foo();
delete foo;
foo->bar();
```

and as long as code in Foo::bar doesn't do anything with `this` pointer. My first question is, is this undefined behavior that happens to work or is it according to standard?

Second question:

If we alter code to:

```
Foo * foo = new Foo();
delete foo;
foo = nullptr;
foo->bar();
```

we can in Foo::bar use following check

```
if (this == nullptr) {
    ...
}
```

in order to determine if we operate on valid object. While it doesn't seem like good idea to do this, is there any architecture/design were this could be useful?

Comment: Both cases are undefined. Microsoft's MFC framework actually [makes use](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d64ehwhz.aspx) of the second one, but it won't be portable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a method do not execute any class member it should be a `static` one. A static method can be called always without any object and the compiler gives an error if this is not true.

The check

> `if ( this )`

looks very very dirty to me. Only for test purpose a `assert` sounds helpful. But if I must fear that a method can be called without object, there is no chance to get save that the pointer ( this ) is set valid to `nullptr`. This is bug shifting and not a solution.

And if the method is a `virtual` one, the check for `this==nullptr` comes to late because the vtable ptr could not be found.

The design of a program should handle new/delete in a proper way. Maybe the use of any kind of smart pointers can help.

Comment: I definitely agree. I was just curious if it could be useful somewhere.

Answer (score 6):

Both uses are just plain UB.

`if (this == nullptr)` may even be optimized away by the compiler as `this` is never `nullptr` in legal code. Clang warns about this btw.

**Update:** As of gcc 6, gcc actually does optimize based on assuming `this != nullptr`. They also added a warning. See it [live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/KIAkeHAsOM2OJT4u).

Comment: It's not optimized away, no matter it's not legal to have a function called on a null pointer. I've seen code like that working; my guess is that it has been inlined.

Comment: @PaoloM Of course the compiler does not need to optimize that away, I just say that it is allowed to. Clang warns about this btw.

Comment: Baum is right, Paulo.  The only way a non-static member function can be called with a null `this` pointer is if the caller has exhibited undefined behaviour.    When compiling any statement, a C++ compiler is permitted but not required to assume that no previously executed statement in the program (not just in the current function) has produced undefined behaviour.   Among other things, this means that the compiler is permitted to assume that a non-static member function is never called with a null `this` - in which case `this == nullptr` will always test false.

Answer (score 2):

`foo->bar()` always dereferences `foo`.

Dereferencing a pointer after deleting it gives undefined behaviour.     If Visual Studio happens to give no error, that is happenstance.   Any result is permitted from undefined behaviour, including giving no apparent error.

Setting `foo` to be `nullptr` and then calling `foo->bar()` also gives undefined behaviour, because it dereferences a NULL pointer.   Testing `this == nullptr` inside `Foo::bar()` does not change that, because it is the caller that has exhibited undefined behaviour even before `Foo::bar()` has been called.

Comment: foo->bar() definitely does not always dereference foo.  if bar() is a non-virtual method - the value of foo has nothing to do with the call resolution.

Comment: You're mistaken, Ofek.  Use of the operator `->` dereferences `foo` before `Foo::bar()` is called, and has nothing to do with virtual function dispatch.

Comment: The called function is the same (Foo::bar) regardless of foo's value. The closest thing to a 'dereference' operation involved is passing foo as a hidden 'this' argument to Foo::bar (and only if bar() is non static). If in bar()'s implementation there is no use of members, no dereferencing will take place whatsoever.   Only if bar() is virtual does the call resolution depend on a vtable, obtained using foo's specific contents.

Comment: You're missing the point.    It is the semantics of operator `->` that is the issue.  Any expression of the form `a->b`, including calling a member function as in `a->func()`, only has defined behaviour if `a` is a valid object.   That is specified in the standard.   Yes, a compiler might elect not to access the value of `foo`, but that is not what makes the behaviour defined or undefined.     It is the standard which does that.

Answer (score 0):

```
foo->bar()
```

this statement means decode the address in foo. and put it into the call stack, and then put the variable content of bar to the call stack. Lastly, execute the function.

If the ::bar() function is completely empty. It is OK.

Otherwise, even you just declare some variable. The address of *foo is already dirty by your function call.

1) If the foo == nullptr. 0x0000000 is a read only section, your program will crash, or throw exception when your main is end.

2) If the foo != nullptr, but it is deleted. The heap will corrupted, and the memory barrier may detect your action, it may crash

3) If the foo != nullptr, and it is stack variable. The stack is dirty and it will crash.

Comment: That is not how a call stack works.  The 'variable content' of bar() is not a thing. The address of the function bar() is used directly by a 'call' instruction, if bar() is virtual - it is obtained first from the type's vtable, but is never 'put on the stack'. The address of foo is passed as a hidden parameter to bar() - typically via the ecx/rcx register and not on the stack.

Comment: you are right, the this pointer is not push into the stack. But I assume there are variables declared inside the function ::bar().     After the vtable entry resolved, the function call is still push to the stack, and the declared variable also pushed. So the stack will be dirtied